# How to monitor file access for an OS X application?

Tags: terminal, activity-monitor, unix

I am looking for the OS X corespondent of FileMon, that was later included in [ProcessMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

BTW, it is essential to be able to filter by process.

Comment: I'll add three options - since the unix heritage of Mac OS X is different than the NT architecture - the tools don't overlap perfectly. Are you looking for an API to program or just tools to peek at what is currently happening (or trigger actions after a certain file changes)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Instruments—a part of the Apple Xcode development suite—can monitor all file access and writes. Open it from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app, select your application or process, and press Start. You have extensive filter options available in the menus.

Older versions of Xcode are storing the App at /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app

Comment: As of Xcode 5, this is now located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app - and can also be reached from within the XCode app - Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Instruments.

Comment: This doesn't work if the file being accessed isn't happening because of your application

Comment: Actually it doesn't works for OS X: "I/O activity does not support the macOS platform".
Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621938/xcode-instruments-this-instrument-does-not-support-osx

Comment: Can you provide more details on this?  Which instrument - Activity Monitor?  I'm seeing a long output for all processes here, not sure how to filter it to disk i/o for one process

Comment: I tried this on a dot file and it would not allow me to choose it.

Comment: How to monitor application from start?

Answer (score 63):

There is the command `opensnoop`. Run without arguments, it may overwhelm you with output, but it can be run with arguments `-n name` to limit output to processes named `name`.

Comment: Similarly `sudo opensnoop | grep .classpath` gives you accesses to a classpath file for example.

Comment: Note opensnoop and Instruments are both front-ends to the same DTrace engine. Other front-ends: http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343423/opensnoop-dtrace-error-on-enabled-probe-id-5-id-163-syscallopenreturn-i if you want to get rid of the dtrace error

Answer (score 21):

No one has mentioned Activity Monitor, found in the `/Applications/Utilities` folder.

Click on the Process Name in the list, then hit the "Inspect" button on the toolbar.

There are three tabs in the resulting window: `Memory`, `Statistics`, `Open Files and Ports`. The `Open Files and Ports` tab will show all the open files being used by the process.

Comment: This doesn't work if the file is being accessed by an unknown application

Answer (score 16):

Launchd is the main system level tool for monitoring files (and a folder is a special file) since it's always running. [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) is one program that helps put a pretty GUI around launchd WatchPaths. Look here for lots of tips on launchd as well as hundreds of tutorials, a good wikipedia article and the Apple dev docs.

fseventsd will log some changes - so you might use [FSeventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) or access those files if launchd isn't your cup of tea.

[fs_usage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) and [lsof](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) are process aware command line tool to tap into the IO subsystem as it's running. The fs_usage buffer can get overloaded so if you want something more guaranteed and less of a "take a quick peek" it's less dependable for total correct results as the other commands.

Comment: I have used FSEventer quite a few times to find out what an application is accessing. This is great when looking for license files for system imaging for lab deployment.

Comment: fseventer is excellent to have the big picture realtime, you really see what's going!.

Comment: Since FSeventer is dead, one could also try [FSMonitor.](https://fsmonitor.com/)

Comment: Doesn't seem like Hazel does this at all, at least anymore? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

> `lsof`

command on the Terminal.app can do that for you?
use the `man lsof` to catch up with it's use.
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The faster way is:

```
$ lsof [path_to_file]
```

This solution doesn't require the root password and gives you back the following, clear, result:

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
Finder     497  JR7   21r   REG    1,2   246223 33241712 image.jpg
QuickLook 1007  JR7  txt    REG    1,2   246223 33241712 image.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Also available are [`iosnoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iosnoop.1m.html) and [`iotop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iotop.1m.html) depending on your specific needs. These terminal commands can be piped through `grep` to watch for filesystem events from a specific process or against a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a graphical interface to `lsof` type information. It's donationware from HAMSoft and it's called [What's Keeping Me](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html). Designed to answer that "Why can't I delete this from my trash?" question that comes up every so often on OS X, it also happens to be a handy way to watch for open I/O handles on running processes if you're just curious about what's going on. It allows you some simple search and filtering.

Comment: The domain was taken over by another (shady-looking) outfit in 2022. You can still download a zip of the last version, 2.4, from the link at archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20210415173731/http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html It's an Intel binary, but works on Apple Silicon with Rosetta.