# Persistent/permanent ApplePressAndHoldEnabled?

Tags: keyboard

I use the following command to enable the "Press and Hold" functionality which is important for me to write text with language characters:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

However, every now and then for some reason setting gets reset and only starts working again after a reboot.

How can I have this setting be permanent without anything else interfering with it?

Update: at least in some (all?) cases the value is still true, but the popup does not come anymore until I reboot.

Comment: Would creating a cron/deamon job to keep setting that back to true every hour be feasible?

Comment: @user14492 if only apps would react to those changes right away that would be a good solution.

Comment: hmmm that'll be difficult to find out what is changing it back. Could perhaps options from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application help?

Comment: As an alternative the character picker for language characters you might want to also consider the standard option key shortcuts https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemac/