# Can I trace movement of files on macOS?

Tags: macos, file

I would like to be able to collect data on file movement to filter it by time, type and/or size.

Is there a procedure or third party app that will allow tracing of any file as it moves from a place of origin to external drives or even to other internal folders?

Comment: Try FortiAppMonitor or fs_usage.

Comment: Does this (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application) answer your question?

Comment: Yes...it's called Auditing but it's only limited to the system being audited.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304981/119271  Until files have some sort of blockchain audit built into it, once it leaves the system, you have no idea where it went.